# How to bind a jar file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How can I bind a 3rd party library (.jar file) in my java source? Are there any tutorials for this?

Comment: What do you mean "bind" ? You mean use it?

Comment: i mean to attach it to project so i can access its functions

Comment: He said eclipse right in the title ... the process is the same for virtually all versions of eclipse

Comment: Sorry, missed that... I may be weird, but most times I find myself reading the question and ignoring the title, which is why it annoys me when the question is not self-contained. It's like those "as the subject says" e-mail messages I get sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

I normally drag-and-drop the jar file in the project (in a suitable folder), and then right click it and select Build path -> Add to build path.

You can now use it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the project in question
2. Point to build path
3. Click "Configure Build Path" in the menu that open
4. Click "Add External JARs" -- find your JAR
5. Click OK

You'll need to package your external JAR with your main application if you distribute it. But that'll at least get you going in Eclipse.

-- Dan